How to calculate the minimum ada sent in a transaction?
When I use Eternl wallet to send ADA, and I type "0.8" ADA, it automatically gives me "0.969750". How is this calculated in this current era? (either Babbage era or Conway era)
There's this minimum allowed ADA for me to be able to spend, and it seems like I can't send anything below 0.969750 ADA.
So I'm really curious about how is this calculated, as the parameter for MinUtxoValue was deprecated a long time ago

The transaction fee calculation mechanism is part of the protocol parameters. It consists of two components; a constant fee and a fee per byte of tx size.
See https://cexplorer.io/article/understanding-cardano-fees

Thank you, but that's not what I'm asking. I was asking why I couldn't send any amount below 0.969750 ADA. The last time in 2021, it was because of the minUtxoValue parameter that was set to 1,000,000 Lovelace, which was deprecated sometime in 2022 epoch 290. So I'm looking for any docs on how the minimum ADA is calculated in the current era
